# Update - aggregation function in the where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Why this sql instruction doesn't work...?

I want to update the salaries by 15% for all employees who have salaries lower than average ...

`UPDATE Employers
SET salary=salary * 1.15
WHERE salary < (SELECT AVG(salary) FROM Employers);`

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error it gives you? You're missing a `)` towards the end. `(SELECT AVG(salary) FROM Employers);`

Comment: Sorry :). But this is not the problem...In mysql, i have the following message: 
#1093 - Table 'Employers' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like you're battling a restriction of MySQL: ["You cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery."](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html). Not to say there isn't a solution, personally I'm just not aware of it. Someone who knows more may be able to provide a solution for you!

Comment: Thank You all! :)
I find a solution. This is also like this:

UPDATE Employers
SET salary = salary *1.15
WHERE salary<(SELECT * FROM (
SELECT AVG(salary ) 
FROM Employers) AS salEmp);

Answer (score 0):

Could be you need an alias

```
  UPDATE Employers
  SET salary=salary * 1.15
  CROSS JOIN ( (SELECT AVG(salary)  avg_salary FROM Employers) ) t 
  WHERE salary < t.avg_salary;
```